# is it possible to define a enum with key value in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am receive a status code from server side using Dio in flutter, the code `904` tell me not login error, then I want to define a readable enum in flutter like:

```
enum ResponseStatus {
  NOT_LOGIN(904),
}
```

then I could compare using the key, and write like this:

```
ResponseStatus.NOT_LOGIN.key==Respone.StatusCode
```

it is more readable, but now I can only define a enum like this in flutter:

```
enum ResponseStatus {
  NOT_LOGIN,
}

enum ResponseStatus {
  904,
}
```

it is possible to implement the better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope I understood your question you can create an extension for ResponseStatus
and then set the  codes or description for the enum

```
 extension ResponseStatusExtension on ResponseStatus  {

  static const statusCodes = {
    ResponseStatus.not_login: 904,

  };

  int get statusCode => statusCodes[this];

}
```

it's more accessible and easy to use in my opinions

then you can access it buy using

```
  final  status = ResponseStatus.not_login;
  print('ResponseStatus name: ${status.statusCode}');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extensions for your purpose.

```
main(List<String> arguments) {
  final status = ResponseStatus.NOT_LOGIN;
  print('status code: ${status.key}');
  print('status code: ${status.keyWithSwitchCase}');
}

enum ResponseStatus {
  NOT_LOGIN,
  LOGIN
}

extension ResponseStatusExtension on ResponseStatus {
  static const Map<ResponseStatus, int> _map = {
    ResponseStatus.NOT_LOGIN: 904,
    ResponseStatus.LOGIN: 905
  };

  int get key => _map[this];
  
  int get keyWithSwitchCase {
    switch (this) {
      case ResponseStatus.NOT_LOGIN:
        return 904;
      case ResponseStatus.LOGIN:
        return 905;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Flutter 3.0 you can abandon extensions and write enum like this:

```
enum ResponseStatus {
  notLogin(904),
  login(905);

  const ResponseStatus(this.code);
  
  final int code;
}
```

It's a preferred new way.

More on new enums is [here](https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/using-enums-like-a-pro-in-flutter-4563dde2e8a9).